# Low clutch biting point

Tags: ford, clutch, manual-transmission, ka

I have a 62 plate 1.2 Ford KA Zetec. I’ve had it about a year and have been having problems for about 6 months.

If I am creeping forward in traffic for longer than five minutes, the bite starts to get progressively lower to the floor, to the point that with the pedal on the floor- the car is at the bite. At this point I can’t get the car into gear either.

It has gotten to the point where I have gotten stuck in a drive through and had to turn the car off and pump the clutch pedal to slip it into gear.

This is getting rather annoying and irritating as I can’t drive my car through traffic without worries of being stuck.

I’ve had this seen by the same mechanic twice and he says that there’s nothing wrong with my clutch.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Consider bleeding/flushing the clutch master cylinder. It is possible the brake fluid in the clutch master cylinder has absorbed water and is boiling after a long idle. The resulting air pocket lowers the pressure in the slave cylinder.

Comment: Does the car still have a warranty? Definitely a transmission issue. See a different mechanic (one who works on standard transmission cars), or even take it to the dealer.

Comment: Similar as this one>>>>>https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/74298/94-toyota-pickup-hard-to-put-into-gear-after-clutch-in-too-long/74299

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your problem is the master cylinder is not holding pressure. More than likely this will need to get replaced. I'm not sure on your vehicle if it can be replaced by it self or if you have to replace it along with the slave cylinder.

One temporary solution is to put the vehicle in neutral while sitting still, taking your foot off of the clutch pedal. As long as you aren't consistently putting pressure on the clutch pedal, the fluid should not be slipping past the master cylinder. It should at least provide you a means you wouldn't have to deal with needing to pump up the system as often.